# Windows Server 2008 - Non-Domain users can see my server shares

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

Windows Server 2008 - Server Machine
Windows 7 Professional - Client Machine

I have a domain. It was setup by the client.  The shares on the server are restricted correctly when a user logs on to the domain and uses their workstation, I have a few groups setup to restrict some access but the groups are at their core "Domain Users".
The problem I am having is that when a user brings in a laptop with Windows 7 Pro on it,  they can type up the name of the server in the "Run Dialog" on the start menu like "\SERVERNAME\"  and access all of the shares freely... because they are not logged in to the domain there are no restrictions it seems.
I have reviewed the permissions on the folders and they all have to be "Domain Users" and I have removed "Everyone" from the list of people able to see it. Guest access is also disabled...
What am I doing wrong? Only group in the list is "Domain Users" isn't a domain user a user that is logged in to the domain? How do I stop non-domain users from seeing the shared folder?
I noticed this on Windows Server 2003 too at another time. I assume they both had similar security issues and neither were set up by myself so I am not sure what could have been enabled or specifically deactivated that makes this issue appear.
I am looking at the Security >> Permissions and not "Share Permissions" but wouldn't the security permissions stop read/write on non-authenticated domain users?

Comment: They can see the Shares or they can access the Shares? What are the Share permissions (not the NTFS permissions)?

Comment: Both. I am checking the sharing permissions in about an hour when I arrive on location. My guess is the current admin has it set as "Everyone"

Thanks for the down vote everyone! That makes for a good learning atmosphere!

Comment: "Thanks for the down vote everyone!" - You got 1 downvote. That's hardly everyone. Yes, it sucks but it's part of being here so get used to it and don't let it put you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of permissions on shared folders, and you haven't explained which set you're looking at - and you haven't explained if the non-domain users can actually read files, or if they can just see the share names.

I'm guessing that you've examined the NTFS permissions on the files and folders, and those don't allow "everyone". But I bet that your share permissions (which are set in a different place) are set to allow "Full Control" to "Everyone". That's not a big issue - the more-restrictive set of permissions will mean that these anonymous users can't do anything else besides read the names of the share.

That's my guess, based on what you've said.

However, if they can access and read the actual files, then either you're missing something in the NTFS permissions, or they are successfully authenticating to the server. If their local username on the non-domain machine is the same as their domain username, and the password is the same, the client may be attempting (and succeeding) at passing NTLM authentication.

From the server, why don't you bring up Sessions under Shared Folders in Server Management and see what's going on from that perspective?

Comment: I am looking at the "Securit >>Permissions" not Sharing Permissions

These are excellent suggestions.  I stumbled upon the "Share Permissions" after writing this. I am going to look in to it shortly.  The local user name and password is not used as a domain user id and password so it wouldn't be that one.

The (non-domain) user is in fact able to read/write even though the Security>>Permissions does not have "everyone" in it.  They only contain "Domain User".

I will post again when I look at the Sharing. But it seems as though something may still be wrong besides that as they can read/write?

Comment: Yes, there's clearly something wrong - your understanding of the configuration or the situation must not match the reality. The user may have done a "net use" or the GUI "map a network drive" and supplied their domain credentials. Or there's a mistake or misunderstanding in what you've configured for permissions. The windows security model won't let a user without the proper token have access to an object (like a file) that has a DACL configured. Citation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Clearly... The user has not logged in to anything.  I have not been back to the site yet, I have tested this out on a 2008 install I did internally to try to prove it out, and if I set the sharing permissions correctly then everything is fine.  If I only set the NTFS permissions then there is mixed results.  That is the reality I am facing.

Thank you for your help mfinni, I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Also thank you for the tip about bringing up sessions, that revealed a lot of useful information for us.